# Can't attach to Silverlight application with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, debugging, process, silverlight-4.0

Few days ago all was ok: when I started my web-site with Silverlight 4.0 application with F5 in Visual Studio debugger was connecting to Silverlight automatically, but now it doesn't.

I've tried to attach manually from "Debug"->"Attach to process" with "Attach to" option set into "Silverlight code" value. But my breakpoints are still "disabled"...

Why? How can I resolve that?

Thanks.

P.S. I've created new Silverlight project recently - and is been able to attach to silverlight without any problems...

Comment: Is Managed Code enabled for the debugger? When you go to the attach to  process window, make sure it is selected.

Comment: On attempt to switch on 'Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0)' or 'Manager (v4.0)' debugging the dialog with text appears:
"Managed degugging is not compatible with Silverlight. Would you like to uncheck Silverlight?"... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My xap-file of the Silverlight app is not being updated after compilation: I've added another control - it didn't appear in my app...

The reason: Silverlight app contained wrong "Startup Object". After fix - problem was resolved.

P.S. Sorry for stupid question.

Answer (score 4):

check the debugger settings in the ASP project that is hosting your silverlight application, make sure silverlight is checked.  Go to Properties->Web tab->Debuggers, check Silverlight

[image: Debuggers Selection]

Comment: Luke, all my setting are same as your... Thank you, but that didn't help... :(

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the *.xap file solved it for me. I guess I'll have to delete it often.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see often is that the browser is caching the XAP so the changes are not seen.  Deleting the XAP doesn't always fix this, one easy solution to this is to add a unique number to the xap reference in the HTML/ASPX file and just increment it when you want to force a reload (e.g here I user ver param):